# Can't get chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal working between extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, messaging

In extension with id `aglpopilkbmccegiojppdmbhamchojed` I have in the background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
}
```

In the other extension I have

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('aglpopilkbmccegiojppdmbhamchojed', 'dummymessage')
```

This isn't working. Do I need to add something to the manifest.json file? However, with an appropriate entry in the manifest file, I can send message from a web page. Any clue why it might not be working?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I did need to add to the manifest.json file.

The page at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging by mentioning the manifest file for sending messages from web pages but omitting to mention it for "Cross-extension messaging" mislead me.

Anyway adding following to manifest.json did it

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["*"],
},
```

Comment: This should not be the case __by default__. Quoting the docs: _"If `externally_connectable` is not declared in your extension's manifest, all extensions and apps can connect, but no webpages can connect."_ So this must've happened because you added an explicit key for some website.